# How to debug babel.config.js

Tags: javascript, react-native, babeljs

I've noticed that there are virtually no info from babel on incorrect configuration. For example I've created new app with `react-native-cli`, installed decorators plugin and filled my `babel.config.js` as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
};
```

And there were the same complain as if no plugin is installed. Correct config would be:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }]],
};
```

Now I'm trying to install [jsx-control-statements](https://github.com/AlexGilleran/jsx-control-statements) and have the same silent fail causing
`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Choose` as if no such plugin is installed at all. My `babel.config.js` is:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    'jsx-control-statements',
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
  ],
};
```

So the question is: **How do I debug this configuration? How can I get some diagnostic from babel about incorrect configuration/not found packages etc.?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For instance if the presets/plugins are missing or missconfigured, you'll get an error when webpack takes over and try to load all the config. But I think your best shot is to use progressPlugin where you could display each step and see for yourself what is happening.

```
new webpack.ProgressPlugin((percentage, message, ...args) => {
    console.log(percentage, message, ...args);
  }),
```

Another approach, would be using [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) module, as nearly all other plugins, modules use it.

```
DEBUG=* webpack [-c webpack.something.js]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: this is for [@Ilya Denisov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/986783/ilya-denisov), I had to add code snippets to be clear

Answer (score 1):

If you use `babel.config.js` you could do the following:

```js
module.exports = function(api) {
  if (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    api.debug = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || false;
  }

  const presets = ['@babel/preset-env'];
  const plugins = [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    ...
  ];
 
  return {
    presets,
    plugins,
  };
};
```

Comment: And how would I know if some of the listed plugins/preset are not available and will not be loaded (e.g. because of typo like in a provided example)? If I don't see a typo in object/array literal then I will not see it in printed form as well.

Or am I missing something?